# Downloading fails from ftp server using TMS Webcopy software in Delphi xe3

Tags: delphi, ftp

Hi i am trying to use TMS software to download a file. But cannot seem to get the file to download.

i use the following code, and have written in an exception handler which keeps telling me that the URL cannot be found. Any help would be appreciated.

```
main.WebCopy1.Items.Clear;
 with main.WebCopy1.Items.Add do
  begin
   FTPHost :=fHost;
   FTPUserID := fusername;
   FTPPassword := fPass;
   URL := '\Setup\libmysql.dll';
   Protocol := wpFTP;
   CopyNewerOnly := true;
   TargetDir := 'c:\Program Files\myfolder\';
  end;
 main.WebCopy1.Execute;
```

May i just add, i just tested the same code and url in another project that i had written and it worked.

Thank You

Comment: Can you post the full error message and exception class, and maybe a stack trace?

Comment: Does the component allow backslashes in the URL (URLs use slashes as path separators, but maybe the component does a replace).

Comment: no it does not. That problem has already been solved. I replaced the '\Setup\libmysql.dll' with '/Setup/libmysql.dll'.

And i do not get an error message, i built my own error message in on the OnUrlNotFound event, if i leave it out, i do net get a error, nothing happens.

So i do not know why the same code works in 1 project, but fails in another?

Comment: This is the error handler.
procedure TMain.WebCopy1URLNotFound(Sender: TObject; url: string);
begin
showmessage('Url not found: '+url);
end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys i found the problem. The connection was not set to passive.
I checked on the server and could not find that any connection was being made to the ftp account, and realized that the problem was not the path, it was the connection.

So i checked and saw the connection was set to passive, changed it an vualla, it worked.

So Now We know, For it to work passive must be set to true.

Thanks alot anyway guys

Answer (score 0):

Things I would try:

- use the debugger and check the code which connects and sends the HTTP request
- check your HTTP server log file to see which resource has been requested
- use a HTTP proxy (Fiddler) to intercept and analyze the HTTP traffic between the Delphi application and your HTTP server
- extract the relevant part of the two projects, then diff their sources

(both with the working and the non-working application).